# Where does ISP obtain their IP address from in order to connect to internet?

Tags: networking, ip, internet, isp, address

To my little knowledge, my home computer can connect to internet because the ISP assigned a dynamic IP address to my router. Then through NAT, the router assign an dynamic IP address for my home computer.

So now my question is where does the ISP obtain their own IP address from to connect to internet?

Answer (score 3):

From a block of addresses provided by an address provider such as ARIN or RIPE.

Comment: So if I want to become an ISP. That means I would need to contact ARIN or RIPE for registering an IP address?

Comment: You would have to contact them for a block of addresses.

Comment: Oh, and be quick about getting your addresses.  They are going fast, in a short time they will all be gone.

Comment: 61 days to go .. (approximately) .. http://twitter.com/ipv4countdown